# django login_required defaults request.LANGUAGE_CODE to default language in settings

Tags: python, django

**login_required** decorator sets **request.LANGUAGE_CODE** to default language that has been set in **settings.py**. How can I bypass this behavior ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue in the past and found that setting your LOGIN_URL in the settings file to use reverse_lazy works:

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('log_in')
```